# Using add_predictions() to predict the variable on the righthand side of a linear model (lm)

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm, predict

I've used some standard data to model the relationship between two variables. The best fit is `y ~ log(x)`. `y` is a variable called `ct`, and `x` is a variable called `standard_conc_ngul`. I've got some new data, where I only know the y values (ct). I want to predict the x values (standard_conc_ngul). However, the `add_predictions()` function only works in the other direction, predicting y from x.

Here's some model data.

```
model_data <- structure(list(standard_conc_ngul = c(50, 50, 50, 5, 5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.005, 0.005), ct = c(16.263463973999, 
15.9799518585205, 15.8724918365479, 19.6285934448242, 19.5386505126953, 
21.3258514404297, 21.9189949035645, 23.639965057373, 23.511137008667, 
23.7562923431396, 25.9067344665527, 25.987663269043)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

> print(model_data)
# A tibble: 12 × 2
   standard_conc_ngul    ct
                <dbl> <dbl>
 1             50      16.3
 2             50      16.0
 3             50      15.9
 4              5      19.6
 5              5      19.5
 6              0.5    21.3
 7              0.5    21.9
 8              0.05   23.6
 9              0.05   23.5
10              0.05   23.8
11              0.005  25.9
12              0.005  26.0
```

I model the relationship between `ct` and `standard_conc_ngul` like this:

```
ggplot(model_data, aes(x = standard_conc_ngul, y = ct)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ log(x)) +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~ log(x),
               aes(label = paste(after_stat(eq.label), after_stat(rr.label), sep = "~~~")),
               parse = TRUE, coef.digits = 3, f.digits = 3, p.digits = 3, 
               rr.digits = 3)
```

[image]

```
model = lm(ct ~ log(standard_conc_ngul), data = model_data)
model_summary <- summary(model)

> model_summary$r.squared
[1] 0.9857383
```

I've then got some new `ct` data.

```
new_data <- structure(list(ct = c(36.4112663269043, 38.2640724182129, 32.7499198913574, 
34.9506607055664, 35.1940498352051, 33.6090316772461, 36.1515579223633, 
33.9076690673828, 30.9849720001221, 35.2763442993164, 35.5483360290527, 
28.1783123016357, 36.2575035095215, 37.1801261901855, 35.7146415710449, 
34.3365440368652, 35.3149261474609, 31.3500270843506, 36.0679473876953, 
28.4723072052002, 38.3946990966797, 33.8331108093262, 35.9874420166016, 
35.9941635131836, 34.1121406555176, 36.4313087463379, 33.7280616760254, 
31.6534538269043, 35.2425842285156, 37.5738525390625, 28.8860301971436, 
37.6940841674805, 33.6983222961426, 36.7991371154785, 35.6302680969238, 
33.453369140625, 29.2328281402588, 34.8536720275879, 36.5731735229492, 
26.4282283782959, 32.1904258728027, 36.5712852478027, 34.5956192016602, 
24.9539623260498, 33.6246643066406, 29.2099666595459, 35.8060531616211, 
38.0736312866211, 32.7279891967773, 37.5331420898438, 34.4548606872559, 
35.3194236755371, 38.7736511230469, 26.102840423584, 37.6750679016113, 
32.389274597168)), row.names = c(NA, -56L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

But `add_predictions` won't let me predict `standard_conc_ngul` from the `ct` values.

```
> new_data %>%
+     add_predictions(model, var = "standard_conc_ngul_predicted")
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  object 'standard_conc_ngul' not found
```

Any suggestions for how to predict them?

I've tried reversing the variables on the x and y axes, but then I can't make the model fit:

```
ggplot(model_data, aes(x = ct, y = standard_conc_ngul)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ exp(x)) +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = x ~ exp(x),
               aes(label = paste(after_stat(eq.label), after_stat(rr.label), sep = "~~~")),
               parse = TRUE, coef.digits = 3, f.digits = 3, p.digits = 3, 
               rr.digits = 3)
```

[image]

```
model = lm(standard_conc_ngul ~ exp(ct), data = model_data)
model_summary <- summary(model)
> model_summary$r.squared
[1] 0.1144794
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What about fitting `x ~ y` and then using that model to make the x predictions?

Comment: Thanks @jonathan-v-solórzano, but this is a log function. I've tried flipping the variables on the x and y axes, but can't get the formula for the line fit. I've been trying log(y) ~ x, and y ~ 1/x, but can't recreate the 0.9857383 from the first way round. Can you help?

Comment: I've updated above